# M2Eclipse issue on MAC OS X

Tags: eclipse, macos, eclipse-plugin, m2eclipse, m2e

I try to use m2eclipse on MAC OS X (Mountain Lion) with Eclipse...
I installed the plugin in Eclipse JUNO and restarted but I can't see the Maven integration...

- Can't create a Maven project (not listed in project type)
- Can't run Maven clean ou build on a maven project I have imported as 'General project'

I have no issue with this plugin on Windows7, there are issue on MAC OS X ?

Regards,

Chris

Comment: Which plugin, by its name or ID?  How did you install it?

Comment: I use plugin 'm2eclipse' and I installed it with updated site directly in Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you install the correct plugin.  The first one (and the one most people seem to install) is the m2eclipse for WTP plugin which *does not* install m2eclipse.  The one you want is "Maven Integration for Eclipse".

Once this is done and working you need to right click your project and select "Configure -> Configure as Maven Project"